# PHP array merging results with "and" and "&"

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of results, this array is sorted into another array that lists them in order of most mentions:

```
$array = get_cforms_entries();   /* all data, no filters */

$keywords = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $sub) {
foreach ($sub['data'] as $key => $value) {
    $keywords[] = $value;
}
}

$result = array_count_values(array_map('strtolower', $keywords));
arsort($result);

echo '<ul class="winners">';
$i = 0;
foreach ($result as $value => $number) {
    $i++;
echo "<li>$value | $number votes".PHP_EOL. '</li>';


if($i==20) break; 
}
echo '</ul>';
```

The output looks like this:

```
hardwell | 389 votes
deadmau5 | 278 votes
armin van buuren | 214 votes
dada life | 211 votes
avicii | 196 votes
tiesto | 193 votes
zedd | 166 votes
alesso | 162 votes
above and beyond | 160 votes
kaskade | 153 votes
krewella | 146 votes
nicky romero | 133 votes
knife party | 118 votes
steve angello | 114 votes
carl cox | 113 votes
steve aoki | 106 votes
above & beyond | 106 votes
daft punk | 105 votes
calvin harris | 100 votes
diplo | 96 votes
```

**PROBLEM IS:**

I have two results 'above and beyond' and 'above & beyond', realistically these are the same result, how would i merge them into one instead of PHP taking them as separate??

Comment: Run a comparison ignoring `&` and `and`?

Comment: how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code right, do this:

`$keywords[] = str_replace(' and ', ' & ', $value);`

This will swap 'and' for '&'. If you want the opposite, swap the first 2 args in the `str_replace`

Answer (score 0):

```
function clean($n)
{
    return str_replace(' and ',' & ',$n);
}
$result = array_count_values(array_map('strtolower', array_map('clean',$array)));
```

Or if you are using php 5.2+ you can use lambda function for elegance

```
$result = array_count_values(array_map('strtolower', array_map(function($n){return str_replace('and','&',$n);},$array)));
```

Comment: so you posted the same answer as i did..except yours will also replace 'and' inside other words. For example 'dandelion' will become 'd&elion'.

Comment: Unfortunately I hadn't seen your answer when I posted mine.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `preg_replace` to match anything that has an `&` or an `and` with spaces surrounding it and normalize it to `and` and then assign the index/key value of `$keywords[]` to be that value:

```
$keywords = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $sub) {
    foreach ($sub['data'] as $key => $value) {
        $raw_keyword = preg_replace("/\s+[\&|\and]\s+/", " and ", trim($value));
        $keywords[$raw_keyword] = $raw_keyword;
    }
}
```

I also added `trim` to filter the $value since it seems like you might be dealing with data that might have inadvertent white-spaces. Feel free to drop that if that seems excessive.